# MediaStream is ended after setRemoteDescription on negotiation

Tags: javascript, socket.io, peerjs

Inside my video conference application, I want to implement screen share feature. I am using PeerJs library and since they don't have the support to such feature, I have to build it from WebRTC API. I am currently facing the following issue: when I start the negotiation between connected peers, to add the share screen track to the peerConnection, and I setRemetoDescription with the offer, the stream from the Peer that wants to share the screen, is ended, losing the current video stream.

Is there a way to prevent that? Is this something related to the PeerJs library? Am I doing anything wrong?

This is my function when a user wants to share the screen:

```
const shareScreen = async () => {
    if (myPeer) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getDisplayMedia({ video: { cursor: "always" }, audio: true })
        .then(async (stream) => {
          myStream.addTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
          setMyScreenStream(stream);
          if (Object.keys(peerConnection).length !== 0) {
            peerConnection.addTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0], myStream);
            peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
              try {
                console.log("negotiating");
                const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
                await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
                socket.emit("negotiation", {
                  desc: peerConnection.localDescription,
                });
              } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
              }
            };
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

And then, on my socket:

```
 socket.on("negotiating", async ({ desc }) => {
        try {
          if (desc) {
            if (desc.type === "offer") {
              console.log("desc type", desc.type);
              await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(desc); // Here the Stream is ended.
            } else {
              console.log("Unsupported SDP type.");
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
```